# HTTP ERROR 500: malformed header from script 'index.php'

Tags: php, heroku, ussd

I get the error "malformed header from script 'index.php'" When i try to run my app from Heroku. trying to test the app on the Heroku platform. I have tried recommitting the project and still does not work. And i cannot see whats wrong with the "Bad header: 2. My Phone Number" that the logs are referring to.

```
//Reads the variables sent via POST from AT Gateway
$session_id = $_POST['sessionId'];
$service_code = $_POST['serviceCode'];
$mobile_number = $_POST['mobileNumber'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

if ($text == "") {
    //first request from user
    //We start the response with a 'CON'
    $response = "CON What would you like to check? \n";
    $response = "1. My Account \n";
    $response = "2. My Phone Number";
}elseif ($text == "1") {
    //Business logic for the first level respone
    $response = "CON Choose account information you want \n";
    $response = "1. Account Number \n";
    $response = "2. Account Balance";
}elseif ($text == "2") {
    //Business logic for the first level response
    //This is a terminal request, Note how we start with END
    $response = "END Your phone is ".$mobile_number;
}elseif ($text == "1*1") {
    //Business logic for the second level
    $accountNumber = "ACC1001";
    //This is a terminal request, Note how we start with END
    $response = "END Your Account is ".$accountNumber;
}elseif ($text == "1*2") {
    //Business logic for the second level
    $accountBalance = "R10 000.00";
    //This is a terminal request, Note how we start with END
    $response = "END Your account balance is ".$accountBalance;
}
header("Content-type; text/plain \r\n");
echo $response;
?>

Error Logs:

2021-02-08T10:58:28.459533+00:00 app[web.1]: [Mon Feb 08 10:58:28.458535 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 155:tid 140511918679808] [client 10.35.179.103:34992] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 2. My Phone Number, referer: https://dashboard.heroku.com/
2021-02-08T10:58:28.459878+00:00 app[web.1]: [Mon Feb 08 10:58:28.458601 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 155:tid 140511918679808] [client 10.35.179.103:34992] AH01070: Error parsing script headers, referer: https://dashboard.heroku.com/
2021-02-08T10:58:28.460241+00:00 app[web.1]: [Mon Feb 08 10:58:28.458630 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 155:tid 140511918679808] (22)Invalid argument: [client 10.35.179.103:34992] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : , referer: https://dashboard.heroku.com/
2021-02-08T10:58:28.460622+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.179.103 - - [08/Feb/2021:10:58:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\ussd\thabo-ussd\thabo-ussd>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `header()` function's content is malformed.

`\r\n` should not be in `header()` and the `;` should be `:`.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Comment: I changed my code to the above but i am still getting the same error:

Comment: 2021-02-08T11:24:15.025566+00:00 app[web.1]: [Mon Feb 08 11:24:15.024611 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 153:tid 140510928828160] [client 10.111.188.18:29323] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 2. My Phone Number
2021-02-08T11:24:15.025847+00:00 app[web.1]: [Mon Feb 08 11:24:15.024662 2